# Joint density calculation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ have a (standard) normal distribution; with zero mean and unit variance.

Let $Y=WX$ where $\mathsf P(W=1) = \mathsf P(W=-1) = \tfrac{1}{2}$.

What are the joint and conditional probability functions: $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ , and $p_Y(y\mid X=x)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: by definition, $\;p_{X,Y}(x, y) = p_X(x)\;p_Y(y\mid X=x)$

So if you find one you find the other.

Now, $p_X(x)$ is the **probability density function** of a *standard normal probability distribution*.  You should know what that is, right?

The other things you know are the **probability mass function** of $W$, and that $Y=WX$.

So can you can use this to express $p_Y(y\mid X=x)$ in terms of $\;\mathsf P(W=\text{something})\;$ ?

Comment: Can you help me to find the probability mass function of w, that is P(w)=?

Comment: @GoitonHasa The probability mass function of $W$ is: $F_W(w)=\mathsf P(W=w) =\begin{cases}\tfrac 1 2 & : w=1\vee w=-1\\ 0 & : \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$